# SFDX : Create Salesforce scratch org with Github actions throws a "Value is not a string" error

Tags: salesforce, github-actions, command-line-interface, sfdx, salesforce-sfdx

I am trying to create a simple yml file for a Github Action to create a scratch org.

After correctly installing dependencies, authorising dev hubs and executing the sf command sf org create scratch, the build throws a "Value is not a string" error.

Anybody encountered a similar issue before?

Thanks a lot

`
Favorite
Nicholas Gioachini
Create Scratch org with Github actions throws a "Value is not a string" error
Hi all,

I am trying to create a simple yml file for a Github Action to create a scratch org.

After correctly installing dependencies, authorising dev hubs and executing the sf command sf org create scratch, the build throws a "Value is not a string" error.

Anybody encountered a similar issue before?

Thanks a lot

tried with this yml file

```
 # This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "main" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: CHECKOUT CURRENT REPOSITORY IN VIRTUAL MACHINE
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
          
      - name: NODE INSTALL OVERWRITE FOR ISSUE https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2125
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.18.0'
          
      - name: INSTALL SFDX 
        run: npm install @salesforce/cli@2.24.4 --global
      - name: Version
        run: sf --version  
      - name: Auth Dev Hub
        run: sf org login access-token --instance-url XXXX --alias devHub --no-prompt --set-default-dev-hub 
      - name: Create scratch
        run: sf org create scratch --edition enterprise  --alias MyScratchOrg
```

Comment: Have you looked at this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331315/salesforce-cli-is-stuck-in-the-authorization-flow-and-the-device-flow-does-not)? Looks relevant.